# Java EE online banking code example

Tags: jakarta-ee, open-source, financial, onlinebanking

Is there any open source Java EE application for online banking and processing that you guys are aware of?

Say for example I want to implement the whole online banking stack, from front-end, middleware, and back-end. Has anybody open-sourced this before?

Comment: This is too broad. What aspect of banking? You have open source databases, servlet containers, message queues, and operating systems, all of which are regularly used in financial applications. You have finance-specific projects like QuickFIX for trade processing, for instance. But what do you have in mind?

Comment: Currently I'm inclined to vote *not a real question* because, as Sean notes, it's too broad and poorly-defined. What is it you're trying to do? What problem(s) are you having that you'd like us to help with?

Comment: I want to implement the whole online banking stack, from front-end, middleware, and back-end. So is there any opensource J2EE app for online banking?

Comment: Banking is not an area i'd expect to see a big open source project.

Comment: Is this homework (schoolproject) or did a bank hire you as developer?

Comment: this is just a schoolproject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may find some projects that could help to build small parts of a banking stack but nothing covering the front, middle and back office activities (if I understand your question properly). Such a stack or ERP is actually the core of a bank (i.e. specific at some point) and simply represents too much money (to give you an idea, a securities back office costs several hundreds millions euros). I don't know any  bank that would give such an investment to a potential concurrent for free.

Just in case, some links you might want to look at:

- http://openhbci.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.aquamaniac.de/sites/aqbanking/index.php
- https://java-swift.dev.java.net/
- http://www.prowidesoftware.com/en/wife-documentation.html

Comment: Hm there are not many open source software for banking out there. 
I read about Banks are using SAP for their core. How does SAP play its role? Is it a full stack software for core banking?

Answer (score 0):

Online banking implementations are far too large and business-specific to implement as an open source project.